# How to go about proving non enumerability.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm learning about enumerability and I'm working through an exercise which states:

*Show that the set of satisfiable $S_{\infty} sentences$ is not R-enumerable*.

I've been told to look at these problems in two ways examine countability and possibly reducing it to the halting problem but I'm not sure how to approach either method. Could someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: What are $S_\infty$ sequences? Does $R$-enumerable mean recursively enumerable?

Comment: Enumerability is not the same as countability. The contexts are quite different.

Comment: $S_{\infty}$ is the set of constants, relation symbols, and function symbols (infinitely many of each). R-enumerable refers to register-enumerability. (i.e. a set is register enumerable if a program P started with (empty), prints out exactly the words in the set)